# Cannot get function in C to execute properly

Tags: c, function

I have a simple function that I am trying to create. I need this function to add 6 to whatever number the user decides to enter into the program. I have been working with this code for an hour now and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong, even after looking at multiple examples from the course I am taking. I really appreciate the help.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void closing(void);
void addSix(void);
int x;
int result;

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("Please enter a number to add to 6: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    getchar();

    addSix();


    closing();
    closing();



    return 0;
}

void closing(void)
{
    printf("That's all folks.\n");
}

void addSix(void)
{
    int result = x+6;
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
}
```

Comment: You have two local `x` variables (as they should be) and a global `x` as well.  But, `addSix` does not know about the `x` you declared in `main`.  You need to use parameter passing and a return statement from `addSix`.

Comment: This is like a homework question.  Debug this code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got both a global `x` variable outside of main(), and a local `x` inside of main(). The code inside of main() writes to the local `x` while the code in addSix() reads from the global `x`.

Remove the `int x` declaration in main() so that both places access the global `x`.

Comment: I deleted the int x from the main area and now everything is running perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @user3055015 This might make your program work, but it's really the wrong solution. You should stop using global variables. I mean it. Just stop it! Refrain from doing so. Use local variables and pass parameters. Try to re-write the code to do it that way.

Comment: What's wrong with just using global variables? Care to explain?

Answer (score 2):

You have x declared as both a global variable and variable local to main. When you pass x by pointer to scanf, it refers to the local variable, not the global.

You can remove the local declaration of int x in main but this isn't really the best solution. Generally, global variables should be avoided when possible (though they are, of course, sometimes necessary/the best tool for the job).

The best solution in this case is to make x a parameter to addSix(). There are a few options here:

- You can have addSix return the sum and then use that return value
- You can pass the address of x to addSix and have the function modify x itself by using a pointer.

The former would look like this:

```
int addSix(int x) {
    return x + 6;
}
```

The latter would look like this:

```
void addSix(int * x) {
    *x += 6;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two variables named `x`. One is a local to `main`, and the other is a global variable.

The function `addSix` cannot see the local in `main`. It can only see the global variable.

You should change `addSix` so that it is passed the value as a parameter.

```
void addSix(int x)
{
    printf("Result: %d\n", x+6);
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
addSix(x);
```

Or perhaps you want your function to return a value:

```
int addSix(int x)
{
    return x+6;
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
int result = addSix(x);
```

Both of your global variables are needless. Remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You have a global `x`, and a local `x` variable in which you actually save the user input.
Using only the global variable will do the trick for you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;

void addSix(void)
{
    int result = x+6;
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
}


int main()
{
    printf("Please enter a number to add to 6: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    getchar();

    addSix();

    return 0;
}
```